# Jmeter: Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: css, ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I have an application URL. I need to run login test using Jmeter. I recorded the login steps using blazemeter extension of chrome. But when I run it I get below error. I know there have been questions like this, I have tried few and it seems my case is different.

**I have tried:**

1. Added these two lines in jmeter.bat

   set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
   set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
2. Run Jmeter using "Run as Administrator"
3. Download the certificate from here https://gist.github.com/borisguery/9ef114c53b83e553b635 and install it this way
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k581jcWk9M
   Restart the Jmeter but and try again but no luck.

When I expand the error in Jmeter View tree listener I get error on this particular css file: `https://abcurl.xyzsample.com/assets/loginpage/css/okta-sign-in.min.7c7cfd15fa939095d61912dd8000a2a8.css`

**Error:**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Load time: 268
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2256
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2256
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error for only one .css file and it does not belong to the application under test (i.e. it is an external stylesheet) the best thing you could do is just to [exclude it from the load test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) via `URLs must match` section which lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element.

If you need to load this .css by any means you could also try the following approaches:

1. Play with `https.default.protocol` and `https.socket.protocols` properties (look for the above lines in *jmeter.properties*) file
2. Install [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) into `/jre/lib/security` folder of your JRE or JDK home (replace existing files with the downloaded ones)

Comment: For #2 `security` folder was present in JRE only not in JDK, so copied n replaced downloaded files for jre only. In #1 both lines are commented with values `#https.default.protocol=TLS`, `#https.default.protocol=SSLv3`, `#https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1` . Dont how to play with these. I guess I need to un-comment them but what value need to put?

Answer (score 0):

If your url needs a client certificate, then copy your cert to **/bin** folder and from the jmeter console if you go to **options -> SSL Manager** and select your cert , it would prompt you for the certificate password . And if you run your tests again , that should work .
Additionally you can also do keystore configuraion (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) , if you haven't done already . 
Please Note that my jmeter version is 4.0 . Hope this helps .