# JMeter with blazemeter recorder Request failed

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for the first time  and I'm trying to run Jmeter script recorder by BlazeMeter recorder for chrome but I'm getting this error

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like this could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885202/jmeter-response-code-non-http-response-code-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexcepti

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the error you're showing to us doesn't contain sufficient amount of information in order to troubleshoot the issue.

Try re-running the request with SSL debug logging enabled, you will need to add the next line to *system.properties*:

```
javax.net.debug=ssl
```

Looking into [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) command output, the protocol appears to be TLS so you will need to add the next line to *jmeter.properties* file as well:

```
https.default.protocol=TLS
```

Also as per the aforementioned curl command output you need to use TLSv1.3

```
curl -vvv https://menthar.joacademy.com/api/v1/users/login
*   Trying 165.22.76.254:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to menthar.joacademy.com (165.22.76.254) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=menthar.joacademy.com
*  start date: Jul 26 17:17:38 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 24 17:17:38 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "menthar.joacademy.com" matched cert's "menthar.joacademy.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x559d2c078db0)
> GET /api/v1/users/login HTTP/2
> Host: menthar.joacademy.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 404 
< server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< date: Tue, 04 Aug 2020 15:41:29 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 21
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-dns-prefetch-control: off
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
< x-download-options: noopen
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< etag: W/"15-5KajTCx0AJD0xogoSeOjjV2M8K0"
< set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3A6x05ZbQfqYUNKn90zBnri0A9b0Hll7kX.xjRMo9p4qmHSMtRYdfxNJtlJCuRQ8ZdgQIKTt5ssbkw; Path=/; HttpOnly
< 
* Connection #0 to host menthar.joacademy.com left intact
```

More information:

- [Diagnosing TLS, SSL, and HTTPS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)